# why do browsers such as Chrome "lock up" whenever a javascript alert is displayed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I consistently see browsers "lock" themselves up whenever an `alert` is displayed. This little trick is also often abused by scamming websites to prevent you from closing the browser, or doing anything else on your computer.

I cannot see a reason as to why a tech giant, such as **Google** would allow (or add) this sort of functionality? It seems like more of a flaw, opposed to a feature.

I am aware that there is a checkbox which asks the user if they would like the alerts to discontinue from displaying, but I have seen countless work-arounds for this.

So, why is it still a thing? Could anyone shed some light as to why this would even be a useful feature (because, as a developer, I've never come across a need to utilise it)?

Thanks.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "modal". Execution of the script is stopped  completely while it's displayed (like for its cousin `prompt()`.) Most modern browsers have mechanisms built in to prevent gross abuse of the feature, and most, I think, no longer let the entire browser UI freeze when one is displayed.

Comment: The answer to this is really "because in 1995 we didn't know any better". And now we're stuck with it. Just like so many other misfeatures maintained for backwards compatibility.

Comment: "*[..]prevent you from closing the browser, or doing anything else on your computer.*" - If it's the latter, then there is something else which is going wrong!

Comment: @Abhitalks I think OP means hijacks the focus.

Comment: `as a developer, I've never come across a need to utilise it` - like seriously? What kind of developer you are if you have never used `alert`/`confirm`/`prompt`? Like before deleting you ask if you really want to proceed.

Comment: @Justinas most people use custom modal dialogs for that. I've *never* used alert for that purpose, even though I do it all the time.

Comment: @Justinas I'm referring to the utilisation of "blocking" the browser, not me actually using `alert`s within my scripts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes down to backwards compatibility. `alert` was designed way back in the 1990s as a modal to be blocking. It would break many scripts if they changed the behavior that depend on it. `prompt` and `confirm` would be impossible to implement without breaking scripts.

At least most modern browsers have the "Prevent this page from alerting" checkboxes.

Comment: What do you mean "blocking"? How would that benefit a users experience?

Comment: @GROVER. blocking is what you mean by "lock up"

Comment: Ahh okay :) that makes sense. What use would be to break the scripts then? Sorry if it seems like an odd question, but it doesn't quite make sense haha

Comment: i mean they left `alert`/`confirm`/`prompt` that way so it wouldn't break them.

Comment: @GROVER. To ask if user really wants to proceed with clicked link...?

Answer (score 2):

It is so because it was (and is) part of the specification.

[The current HTML5 specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#user-prompts) says this under the User Prompts section.

For `alert`:

> Optionally, pause while waiting for the user to acknowledge the
>   message

For `confirm`:

> Pause until the user responds either positively or negatively

For `prompt`:

> Pause while waiting for the user's response.

Browsers (user agents) made the `alert` pause, for the sake of consistency with other user prompts by ignoring the optional part, perhaps.

Also, while we are at it, [the specs say this about `pause`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#pause):

> Some of the algorithms in this specification, for historical reasons,
>   require the user agent to pause while running a task until a condition
>   goal is met. This means running the following steps:
>
> 1. If necessary, update the rendering or user interface of any Document
>      or browsing context to reflect the current state.
> 2. Wait until the condition goal is met. While a user agent has a paused
>      task, the corresponding event loop must not run further tasks, and any
>      script in the currently running task must block. User agents should
>      remain responsive to user input while paused, however, albeit in a
>      reduced capacity since the event loop will not be doing anything.

So, although the specs do say about keeping the user agent responsive, it seems it is not trivial to do so. Because, just after that it says this warning in **bold red**:

> Warning:
>   Pausing is highly detrimental to the user experience, especially in
>   scenarios where a single event loop is shared among multiple
>   documents. User agents are encouraged to experiment with alternatives
>   to pausing, such as spinning the event loop or even simply proceeding
>   without any kind of suspended execution at all, insofar as it is
>   possible to do so while preserving compatibility with existing
>   content. This specification will happily change if a less-drastic
>   alternative is discovered to be web-compatible.
>
> In the interim, implementers should be aware that the variety of
>   alternatives that user agents might experiment with can change subtle
>   aspects of event loop behavior, including task and microtask timing.
>   Implementations should continue experimenting even if doing so causes
>   them to violate the exact semantics implied by the pause operation.

Key takeaway from this is that the implementers are encouraged to look for and experiment with *less drastic* alternatives. However, at the same time *preserving compatibility* with existing content (e.g. blocking scripts).

Comment: @GROVER. Because people don't linger around for long at one question. They move on. :)

Comment: I know, but when a new answer is made on a post, it is normally pushed back to the top of the "featured" tab.

Comment: Yes @GROVER. But, then people see that there is already an accepted answer with votes, so they just move on. That's how it is. But anyway, overall the SO becomes a richer place in larger scheme of things. :)